# Save dynamic button android added by user

Tags: android, button, dynamic, save

I am a beginner in Android and I have a problem in saving Dynamic Buttons.
The code should add a button dynamically when the user needs it.
When users click on addService this code takes (a name for the button and a value to use in the intent for this button) from a second Activity, then adds the button dynamically in this Activity with the name and intent and the user can click it for service.
when we reload the application, Theses buttons will disappear.
How to save the button dynamically added by the user?

Source Code:

```
package com.example.fst.miniprojetandroidn1;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ajouter_programme extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Button> list_programme=new ArrayList<Button>();
    Button Addbutton;
    int count = 1,c;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ajouter_programme);
        setTitle("Liste des programmes ");
        Addbutton = findViewById(R.id.plusbutton);

        Addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Button myButton = new Button(ajouter_programme.this);
                c=count++;

                myButton.setId(c);
                myButton.setText("Programme " + c);
                list_programme.add(myButton);
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                ll.addView(myButton, lp);
              myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ajouterprog();
                    }
                });

            }


        });



    }
    public void ajouterprog(){
        Intent list_programmes_Intent = new Intent(ajouter_programme.this,ajouter_medicamement.class);
        startActivity(list_programmes_Intent);
    }
}
```

amd .xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plusbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ajouter programme"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ArrayList which contains your Buttons is empty because you don't store them. Instead of using that ArrayList (if you don't have any other purpose) you can use SharedPreferences. SharedPreferences uses key-value pair for storing datas. There are two options of SharedPreferences:

**1.Activiy based SharedPreferences:** You can only access with same Activity which you use SharedPreferences. You can't access to that with any other Activities in your App.

```
//Call Activity based SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
//Calling Editor interface for transaction
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
//Put primitive data types (int, String, boolean, float etc.)
editor.putInt(String key, int value);
editor.putString(String key, String value);
editor.putBoolean(String key, Boolean value);
//Apply your changes and finish editing.
editor.apply();
```

**2.Application based SharedPreferences:** You can access on any Activity in your App.

```
//Call Activity based SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(String name,MODE_PRIVATE);
//Calling Editor interface for transaction
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
//Put primitive data types (int, String, boolean, float etc.)
editor.putInt(String key, int value);
editor.putString(String key, String value);
editor.putBoolean(String key, Boolean value);
//Apply your changes and finish editing.
editor.apply();
```

**Note:** *String name* is the name of xml file which your datas will be stored with SharedPreferences and you can name it as you want. Also with SharedPreferences you can only store primitive data types (if you don't use GSON). Store information about your button(s) and recreate everytime you start or resume your Activity.

Getting back datas from Shared Preferences:

```
//Activity based SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
//For getting int
int value = sp.getInt(String key, defautValue);
//For getting String
String value = sp.getString(String key, defaultValue);
//For getting Boolean
Boolean value = sp.getBoolean(String key, defaultValue);
```

**Note:** *int count* will return same value (in this case 1) everytime you start or resume your Activity back. You need to fix it something like:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int count = sp.getInt("count", 1);
```

For example a method for storing information:

```
private void saveButton(int count) {
    //Call Activity (or Application) based SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Calling Editor interface for transaction
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    //Put primitive data types (for this case its integer)
    //Number of buttons
    editor.putInt("count", (count + 1));
    //Ids of each Button
    editor.putInt("btn_id" + count, count);
    //Apply your changes and finish editing.
    editor.apply();
}
```

You can use this method inside on your Button's click method which you're using for creating new a Button. Everytime you click that Button for creating new Button that method helps for saving information about your Button.

For loading your Button(s) back you can use a method like:

```
private void loadButtons() {
    //Find your layout which buttons will be added.
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
    //Call Activity (or Application) based SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Get number of buttons you've saved.
    int count = sp.getInt("count", 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        //Get back required datas for creating for your Buttons again
        int id = sp.getInt("btn_id" + i, 1);
        //Create new button
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Programme" + i);
        btn.setId(id);
        //Add button to your layout
        ll.addView(btn);
        //Set ClickListener for every Button
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ajouterprog();
            }
        });
    }
```

You need to call this method inside onCreate() or onResume() method.